# Opening a particular application from matlab?

Tags: matlab, pdf

I want to open a PDF from matlab with the winopen or open function. I want to use just the Adobe PDF reader for my program but in general want the default application for windows to be Adobe professional. Is there a way to make sure that the Adobe reader is opened and that it opens the file I want opened without having to use Adobe professional and changing my default settings for preferences?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
x = 'row6col8.pdf'
!start acrord32.exe x
```

But this does not work any ways around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`winopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/winopen.html) documentation indicates that the program used to open the file is determined by the filename's extension.

Couldn't you use system commands via `!your-pdf-viewer file.pdf` from matlab, and specify which pdf viewer to use and which pdf file to view?  Something like:

```
>> !start acrord32.exe file.pdf
```

I am not on a windows machine, so I am not sure how of the exact commands to open files from the windows terminal...

Edit:

I see.  You could then do:

```
x = 'filename.pdf';
str = sprintf('start acrord32.exe %s', x);
system(str);
```

Comment: Yes this works but the only problem with this is I need to have the have the file name typed out. I updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my original response to address what you are trying to do.